# Как создать патч для текстового файла?

Tags: linux

Есть ли стандартные средства Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть пара команд `diff` и `patch`. Команда `diff` создает патч на основе исходного и измененного файла. А команда `patch`, применяя патч к исходному файл, производит измененный. Например.

```
diff исходный измененный > патч  
patch исходный -i патч -o пропатченный
```